# Sorting cell text to cell ranges in excel, using macros

Tags: excel, vba, macros, range, cell

Putting it in simple terms: I am looking for a code that puts the text from cell c3 into a range of cells from c5:c75.
For example in range(c5:c75), if the cells c5 and c6 already have text, I would want to fill the cell c7 with my text.
Another example is: if cells c5 and c7 have text but cell c6 doesn't have any text, I would like my text to go there.

Right now my code does not seems ideal, but it goes like this:

```
    Sub check text()
      'In range A1: =Countif(c5:c75;"<>"&"")
If Range("A1") = "0" Then
Range("c5") = Range("c3")

ElseIf Range("A1") = "1" Then
Range("c6") = Range("C3" )

ElseIf Range("A1") = "2" Then
Range("C7") = Range("c3")

'And it keeps going until:

ElseIf Range("A1") = "74" then
Range("c75") = Range("c3")

ElseIf Range("A1") = "75" then
Msgbox("range is full")

End if
```

The problem is the massive size of it, and for it stops working if I have a empty cell between cells with text. For example, if cell c5 has text, cell c6 is empty and cell c7 has text. The code wont work.

Thanks for the time ;-)

Comment: Please do post your codes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looping through all of the cells looking for a blank seems like a lot of work when all of the blanks or the first blank can be retrieved with the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) using the **xlCellTypeBlanks** [xlCellType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx).

```
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    With .Range("C5:C75")
        If Not .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) Is Nothing Then
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1) = .Parent.Range("C3").Value
        Else
            Msgbox("range is full")
        End If
    End With
End With
```

That will locate the first blank cell in the C5:C75 range and fill it with the value from C3.